# find a string in text file and replace the line with variable

Tags: unix, sed

I have variable `ips: "10.34.34.34, 10.42.42.42, 10.55.55.55"`

and cat ips.txt
`ips: ""`

I want to replace the line in my file ips.txt with variable.
    With sed my ips.txt should look like
    cat ips.tx

`sed "s/.*ips*/$varaible/g" ips.txt`

I've tried `sed "s/.*ips*/$varaible/g" ips.txt`;
it did print output, but not replace the line in my file.

How would I replace the line in my file?

`sed "s/.*ips*/$varaible/g" ips.txt`

cat ips.txt should look like
`ips: "10.34.34.34, 10.42.42.42, 10.55.55.55"`

Comment: Please  correct the typo `varaible`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if run this command twice i get the ips listed in ips.txt twice …

Just specify the search pattern so that only the text as it is before the substitution is matched, e. g.:

```
var='ips: "10.34.34.34, 10.42.42.42, 10.55.55.55"'

sed -i "s/ips: \"\"/$var/" ips.txt   # match only with empty quote ("")
```

Answer (score 0):

sed normally outputs to stdout, which defaults to the screen. You can redirect it to a new file like this:

```
sed "s/.ips/$var/g" ips.txt > new_ips.txt
```

If you're feeling brave, you can have the edits occur in place, and change the original file by using the `-i` switch:

```
sed -i "s/.ips/$var/g" ips.txt
```

Note, this can be dangerous. If you make a mistake, the original content of the file is gone.

Comment: thanks alex. if run this command twice i get the ips listed in ips.txt twice like ips: "10.34.34.34, 10.42.42.42, 10.55.55.55,10.34.34.34, 10.42.42.42, 10.55.55.55". how can we replace the entire line instead of just .ips i want the whole content of line like ips: "" replaced with ips: "10.34.34.34, 10.42.42.42, 10.55.55.55" since ips in my text and variable value i'm replacing has ips. when i run the command twice it duplicating the replace twice